# How to move text in PDF?

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfclown, hummus.js

Is there a Java or Nodejs library that can move existing text in a PDF file? 
I'd like to extract all the text nodes, then move some of them to a new location based on some conditions.
I tried PdfClown, galkahana/HummusJS, Hopding/pdf-lib, but seems they don't have exactly what I need.
can anyone help? thanks

Comment: Can you please explain with a bit more detail and maybe even an example?

Comment: With PDFClown I can add content to the page with PageStamper, but I'd like to move an existing text to a new location. Seems this is not directly supported by PDFClown, to walk around it, is it possible to delete or hide the text? I am following the example at [here](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfclown0/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfclown0/extract/TextInfoExtractionSample.java#L132)

Comment: I successfully removed text with PrimitiveComposer by following example at [here](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfclown0/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfclown0/content/HighlightInContent.java)

Comment: but can not re-draw the text deleted, always fails when it tries to get font from current State, the font is null. can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the variables, I figured out how to move text, here is the code

```
PrimitiveComposer composer = new PrimitiveComposer(page);
ContentScanner scanner = composer.getScanner();
tranverse(scanner);
composer.flush();

...

while (level.moveNext()){
    ContentObject content = level.getCurrent();
    if (content instanceof Text){

...    
    List<ContentObject> objects = text.getBaseDataObject().getObjects();
    for(ContentObject co: objects){
        if(co instanceof SetTextMatrix){
            List<PdfDirectObject> operands = ((SetTextMatrix)co).getOperands();
            PdfInteger y = (PdfInteger)operands.get(5);
            operands.set(5, new PdfInteger(y.getIntValue()-100));
         }
     }
```

Comment: This only works sometimes. Sometimes other instructions than setting the text matrix are used to set the position, and depending on the current transformation matrix, subtracting 100 might suddenly mean something different than in your case.

Comment: Hi mkl, I have been waiting for you. your answers and examples helped a lot. the pdf files are all generated by chromium save as pdf, so the text position operation should be consistent. there are some lines printed below where expected, so they mess up with the lines after them. reading and fixing chromium/skia code is too much difficult for me, so I am trying to move those lines up a little to walk around it.

Comment: If you are sure you only get that specific flavor of input PDFs (text in question drawn only in page content streams; only **Tm** used to set text positions without relevant CTM changes), your solution will do what you require. But you could have indicated your specific use case in your question, providing an example document; chances are you would have gotten an early answer then...